# How do I compile directives within an ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
<div ng-repeat="item in entry.items">
    {{ item.prompt }}
</div>
```

item.prompt is a string like this:

```
'Blah blah <input type="text" ng-model="item.answer"> blah'
```

How do I compile this?

item.prompt varies from item to item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do that in this way in your example you just print your html as a string..

```
<div ng-repeat="item in entry.items">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.answer">
</div>
```

**UPDATE**

ok then my suggestion is this just define a wrapper directive and pass your dynamic content as an attribute...

```
<div ng-repeat="item in entry.items">
    <example-dir content="item.prompt">
</div>
```

then in your directive

```
...
$scope.data = $scope.$eval($attrs.content);
element().append($scope.data);
$compile(element)(scope);
...
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant to state that item.prompt is dynamic. It may change.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the purpose of the $scope.data portion. How do I use attrs.content as the template of this example-dir?

Comment: sorry forgot one line

Comment: $compile(element)(scope) freezes my browser. I had to do $compile(element.find('input'))(scope). Thank you though. I used your approach.